# had a question about my code and why it possibly wasnt working any help would be appreciated

Tags: javascript, authentication

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/quiz.css" />
</head>
<body>
// Create the login form
const form = document.createElement('form');
form.method = 'post';
form.action = '/login';

// Create the username input field
const usernameInput = document.createElement('input');
usernameInput.type = 'text';
usernameInput.name = 'username';
usernameInput.placeholder = 'Username';
form.appendChild(usernameInput);

// Create the password input field
const passwordInput = document.createElement('input');
passwordInput.type = 'password';
passwordInput.name = 'password';
passwordInput.placeholder = 'Password';
form.appendChild(passwordInput);

// Create the submit button
const submitButton = document.createElement('button');
submitButton.type = 'submit';
submitButton.innerText = 'Login';
form.appendChild(submitButton);

// Add the form to the page
document.body.appendChild(form);

// Handle the form submission
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault();</body>


    // Get the username and password
    const username = usernameInput.value;
    const password = passwordInput.value;

    // Store the login information in local storage
    localStorage.setItem('username', username);
    localStorage.setItem('password', password);

    // Redirect the user to the homepage
    window.location.href = '/home';
});

<div id="divid">Next</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/quiz.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to create a login screen for a website to get it started I was wondering how i might edit this to make it efficient. This is written in JavaScript. I have 9 errors and when I try correcting them its not working.
Expression expected.ln1 col 1
';' expected. ln1 col 11
JSX element 'meta' has no corresponding closing tag. ln4 col 6
Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'>'}` or `&gt;`? ln38 col 40
'}' expected. ln39 col 27
Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`? ln52 col 1
Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for 'html'. ln57 col 3
Declaration or statement expected. ln 58 col 1
Expression expected. ln 58 col 1

Comment: I fixed most of it all except expression expected &  JSX element "meta" has no closing tag

Comment: why is your javascript code not inside the script tag?

Comment: you can format your code to make it easy to read, also you close the </body> tage twice

Comment: and one of the closing </body> is in the middle of the javascipt code